# Text is overlapping in Table

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pebble

I can see question asked regarding text overlapping for tables (Not header), but none of the result is helping me. please advice.

I have a table with n number of rows (it is a looping with pebble). some time not every, normal text in the table is overlapping to the 1st and 2nd line in the next page, if the table continues to the next page

```
{% for Item in toArray(x.xx.xxx).yy %}
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">
                                        {{ Item.ItemQuantity }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">
                                        {{ Item.ItemDescription }}
                                    </td> 
                                    
                                    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 8px;">
                                        {{ Item.ListItemPrice }} 
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 8px;">
                                        {{ Item.LineNet }} 
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Any solution?

Comment: tried also thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }

Comment: can you screenshot the problem, and / or make an MWE for us to reproduce? Genrally, to fix overflowing text, if you can set the width to a fixed value, you could use ellipsis in `td { width: 49px; overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;}` What exactly you want the result to behave for long texts?